# Iterate Pandas Series to create a new chart legend

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, matplotlib

After grouping etc. I get a Series like in the example below. I would like to show the average numbers for each bar. The code below shows only one entry (of course, as I have only one "legend"). Could anyone one suggest a smart way of showing these numbers?

```
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib
matplotlib.style.use('ggplot')
import pandas

# create Series
dict_ = {"Business" : 104.04,"Economy":67.04, "Markets":58.56, "Companies":38.48}
s = pandas.Series(data=dict_)

# plot it
ax = s.plot(kind='bar', color='#43C6DB', stacked=True, figsize=(20, 10), legend=False)
plt.tick_params(axis='both', which='major', labelsize=14)
plt.xticks(rotation=30) #rotate labels
# Shrink current axis by 20%
box = ax.get_position()
ax.set_position([box.x0, box.y0, box.width * 0.8, box.height])
#create new legend
legend = ['%s (%.1f a day)' %(i, row/7) for i, row in s.iteritems()]
# Put the legend to the right of the current axis
L = ax.legend(legend, loc='center left', bbox_to_anchor=(1, 0.5), fontsize=18)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The legend only has a single entry. This is a handle of a blue bar. Therefore even if you set the labels to a longer list, only the first element of that list is used as label for the existing handle.

The idea can be to duplicate the legend handle to have the same size as the labels

```
legend = ['%s (%.1f a day)' %(i, row/7) for i, row in s.iteritems()]
h,l = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()
L = ax.legend(handles = h*len(legend), labels=legend, loc='center left', 
              bbox_to_anchor=(1, 0.5), fontsize=18)
```

[image]